# How to access function in a class on another file

Tags: python, oop

I am currently working on a text-based adventure game project, I am still fairly new to python and I'm trying to access a class function in a new file. The error I am receiving says *"ImportError: cannot import name 'bedroom' from 'story'"*, how would I fix this error?

*main.py*

```
from story import bedroom

def main():
    while True:
        print("Welcome to  would you like to play?")
        user = input(">>")
        #string handling
        if user.lower() == 'y':
            bedroom()
        else:
            print("See you next time!")
            exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*story.py*

````
import stats as stat

class Rooms():
    def bedroom():
        stat.inventory.append("flashlight")
        while True:
            print("You awake in a dark room with no idea how you got there.\n")
            print("You feel around and feel a flashlight.\n")```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the class itself, not the method.
Try this:

```
from story import Rooms
```

Then, whenever you need to use the method bedroom(), you can call it:

```
Rooms.bedroom()
```